# Memory mapping in Octave with mex-functions

Tags: octave, mmap

I have a plain C code (running on Linux) and I would like to implement it in Octave, so I thought I could use a mex-file for handling the memory mapping and send the information I received (or send) back and forth to my script in Octave and my sensors. The C code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


#define CUSTOM_IP_MAP_SIZE                  0x10000
#define CUSTOM_IP_BASEADDR                  0x43C00000
#define CUSTOM_IP_S00_AXI_SLV_REG0_OFFSET   0
#define CUSTOM_IP_S00_AXI_SLV_REG1_OFFSET   4

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t leds=0x0;
    int fd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDWR);
    void *ptr;

    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ptr = mmap(NULL, CUSTOM_IP_MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    while (1) {
        leds = *((unsigned *)(ptr + CUSTOM_IP_S00_AXI_SLV_REG1_OFFSET));    //Read from the IP (slv_reg1).
        *((unsigned *)(ptr + CUSTOM_IP_S00_AXI_SLV_REG0_OFFSET)) = leds;    //Write to the IP (slv_reg0).
    }

    close(fd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I compiled the code with no errors and the following command:

> mkoctfile --mex mmap.c

I get the following error when I run it in Octave:

> error: failed to install .mex file function 'mmap'

Should I keep trying to do this with a mex-function or there is other option better for this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I always build OCT wrapper and never used MEX but there is also swig module for octave: http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Octave which should make building your wrapper much easier. Btw, have you had a look at the example MEX files in GNU Octave? I doubt they have a "main" function

Comment: I will check the OCT wrapper. Seems a better approach in Octave, right?. I pasted the wrong code. I followed the example from https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles.html to test it in Octave.

Comment: I never heard of UIO before. So you want to build a wrapper to read/write from/to Userspace IO "/dev/ui" from GNU Octave. This looks interesting, should we start a repo on github and work on this together?

Comment: Absolutely! You can see my motivation to do it [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Custom-Hardware-with-UIO/m-p/804303#M22447) and [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Handling-UIO-interrupts-with-callback-functions/td-p/806426)

Comment: okay, I've created a new organization and repo here https://github.com/octave-uio-dev/octave-uio Just give me your github user and I'll add you